# Is there any hope to repair this answer?

Tags: discussion

Well, my answer [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/66641/how-to-respond-to-caste-based-discrimination-in-the-workplace/66895#66895) was deleted surprisingly fast which I see at most partially justifable. My question were, is there any chance to repair the answer.

The essential parts of the answer are:

1. Admitting that the OP doesn't have any chance in his current, personal life.
2. Suggesting him to try to change the world around him into a better one (although it is also probably hopeless in his life)
3. Doing this partially with a conversion from the Hinduism to the Christianity.

I suspect, the main problem of the answer was the #3 or the general attitude. The second I would happily fix.

Essential change I can't do, because it won't be my answer any more. But a significant re-work in the general attitude, I would do happily. Is it possible?

Comment: I think your basic premise is totally wrong, thousands of policemen must face the same issue and they cope with it and get ahead. Also your advice is probably physically dangerous to the OP. On the bright side making me reread the question has enabled me to suggest the perfect strategy, so your typing wasn't a total waste.

Comment: @Kilisi India is a civilized democracy with a significant Christian minority. The life is so terrible there only because it is overpopulated. This overpopulation will lead to a clearly visible catastrophe in the near future. Conversion can mean there a permanent social stigma, but it is clearly not life-threatening. It is also a possibility to collect people thinking similarly to him.

Comment: Civilised is a matter of opinion. And it can easily be life threatening, the OP could get into a bad situation and his fellow policemen could just leave him in it because they dislike Christians.... I was a bouncer I know what that is like. He's in a dangerous profession.

Answer (score 12):

Starting an answer with "You have no hope. Revolve" in all bold is not really an indication you are trying to make an earnest attempt to help the OP.

You then play on the cultural elitism angle praising yourself for being European while simultaneously telling the OP that their society will collapse and telling them they are oppressed by their society sucks to be them.

The key point of your answer was telling the OP to convert to a religion so they can be a martyr. I'm going to assume that really isn't helpful (or appropriate) either.

To top it off you don't make a single attempt to address the OP's situation and constraints.

So no, I really don't think it is salvageable, since the entire focus of your answer is attacking the OP's culture/country, telling them they have no future and are hopeless, and suggesting they change religions and that martyring themselves might be their best bet in life.

If you want to go talk and write about how horrible you think India is, this site is not the place for you.

---

I'll put some effort into talking through the specifics of your answer.

> **You have no hope. Revolve.**

Off to a bad start for being respectful to the asker.

> Convert to Christianity, there are no castes. There isn't even
>   difference between the Christians and the others.
>
> I think, you will also get a permanent social stigma with that. But,
>   from the other side, you will be able to collect people similar like
>   you.

This part is the only real "answer" part here, but is not at all helpful to the OP because:

1. It doesn't talk about how this helps their work situation

   - should they be quitting their job?
   - how do they actually use this information to address their specific questions
2. Brings up significant downsides (social stigma) and doesn't explain how to mitigate them
3. Even assuming good intent, it is written from the perspective of someone completely unfamiliar with India as a country/culture

> Christianity doesn't offer a lot of help for your situation in your
>   life. It doesn't offer anything, except some chance for martyrdom. You
>   can do it only if you accept, that God won't ever reward you in this
>   world.

... this basically says, "actually converting to Christianity won't help. But it will let you have martyrdom. Since your life is going to suck no matter what." Now you've invalidated what you just said since you don't believe it's helpful to the OP unless they want to martyr themselves.

> But: you are right, you are suppressed on injustified, dishonoric
>   ways, and you don't have any hope because the injustice of your
>   society. Christianity was always the religion of the injustufically
>   supressed people.

How is this *not* a direct insult of the OP's country/culture?

> If you don't like the caste system of the Hinduism, liquidate it first
>   in yourself! Leave Hinduism!
>
> I don't think that anything will be better in your life. First, your
>   society will soon collapse because your people can't stop the
>   overpopulation of his area of living.

How is this *not* a direct insult of the OP's country/culture?

> I am happy that I am an European, but don't forget: the price is that
>   my people has at most some centuries back, after that it will dissolve
>   in the so-named "multiculturalism". It essentially means that the
>   future is for the people like yours and not like mine.

This is cultural elitism, again fairly directly insulting country/culture.

> But Christianity can survive, and the justice of the suppressed will
>   also survive until the ethernity.

... what?

---

If you remove everything that is offensive/unneeded your answer essentially has nothing remaining.

Comment: The "revolve" means here doing some unconditional, some... *revolutionary unconditional*, and not actual fight with weapons. If you would read that answer again, I didn't said *"OP to convert to a religion so they can be a martyr"*. This martyr-thing you mention twice, it seems it seriously harmed you. I addressed very clearly the OPs "situation and constraints" (i.e. his hopeless fight with the caste system). I didn't attacked anybody, especially not the culture/country of the OP, except that I condemned the caste system, with it I am probably not alone.

Comment: After perfectly mis-interpreting my writing, you also ask me to leave. May I ask you, *what is your real problem to me*?

Comment: @MorningStar I think a good answer to this question will 1) not focus on how bad of a country the writer thinks India is,  2) respect the asker (ie not tell them their life is hopeless and meaningless) and 3) provide actionable things to do which address their problem and situation. Additionally, should an answer say "convert to Christianity" I would think that there would be a detailed explanation as to how this will help the asker in their current situation as well as how they can manage the social implications such an action would have (particularly in India).

Comment: 1) I didn't said any bad from India in the deleted answer 2) I respected the asker 3) I didn't mention anything about his life, I mentioned his fight against the caste-system is hopeless. 3) My answer was full with actionable things. 4) My answer detailed very clearly, how could it help (mostly not, but he will at least have the possibility to make to world better on a long term). After you again misinterpreted nearly everything I wrote, I need to ask again: *What is you real problem to me?*

Comment: ...and, without a clear answer, I think the real reason is that you simply hate the Christianity, which is really surprising, considering the fact, that I never did any bad for you...

Comment: Recommending someone convert, when they have not asked specifically for that advice, will always be taken badly and trigger irrelevant debates about religion.  Even if you think it would be good for them, it is a bad thing to suggest if you want them-- or anyone else -- to hear anything else you may want to say. For purely strategic reasons, I strongly suggest you abandon that part of your post... Among other things, some people will read it as evidence that Christians are intolerant of other religions. There are appropriate times and places. This is neither

Comment: @MorningStar I added specifics addressing your answer to this.

Comment: Excellent edit, illustrating exactly why this is not a valid answer -- while at the same time being like to to incite an off topic flame-war. I was trying to give the OP the benefit of the doubt and a chance to reach this conclusion on their own, but somtime application of a clue-by-four is needed.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think attacking the Caste system is justified just because you think so. It's a 5 thousand year old system which has basically stopped wholesale genocide in a country with multiple societies by giving each recognition of a sort and a niche. Some niches are better than others, but thats true of any society. The OP's problem is because he's outside his niche, and answers from overseas Indians are a waste of space since by definition they have lost caste by going overseas.

Answer (score 3):

Given the overall message you are trying to convey, your answer is going to be unpopular, even under the best of circumstances.  To mitigate the fallout, you'll want to work carefully to convey your answer in a respectful and thoughtful way.

You may want to give some consideration to the guidelines listed in the [Help Center.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help)  In particular the section titled ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) contains some helpful tips.  For example:

> **Answer the question**
>
> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question
>   asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable
>   alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also
>   include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in
>   the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations,
>   assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable,
>   but fuller explanations are better.

Also, the Help page entitled ["Be Nice - Principles and Practice"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) will be of help to you.  In particular:

> **Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.** Your tone should match
>   the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you
>   want to respect you. If you don't have time to say something politely,
>   just leave it for someone who does.
>
> **Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions.** Don't expect new
>   users to know all the rules — they don't. And be patient while they
>   learn. If you're here for help, make it as easy as possible for others
>   to help you. Everyone here is volunteering, and no one responds well
>   to demands for help.
>
> **Don't be a jerk.** These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag
>   them:
>
> **Name-calling.** Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms
>   that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like "lazy",
>   "ignorant", or "whiny").
>
> **Bigotry of any kind.** Language likely to
>   offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual
>   orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are
>   just a few examples; when in doubt, just don't.)
>
> **Inappropriate
>   language or attention.** Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually
>   suggestive. Also, this is not a dating site.
>
> **Harassment and bullying.**
>   If you see a hostile interaction, flag it. If it keeps up, disengage —
>   we'll handle it. If something needs staff attention, you can use the
>   contact us link at the bottom of every page.